# How can I add Arabic and French as additional languages in react?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, localization

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
function Language() {
    const { pathname, locale, push, asPath } = useRouter();
    const lng = locale == "en" ? "ar" : "en";
    const dir = locale === "en" ? "ltr" : "rtl";
    useEffect(() => {
        document.dir = dir;
        if (dir === "ltr") {
        document.body.classList.add("ltr");
        document.body.classList.remove("rtl");
        } else {
        document.body.classList.add("rtl");
        document.body.classList.remove("ltr");
        }
    }, [dir]);
    const toggleLanguage = () => {
        document.dir = dir;
        if (lng === "en") {
        document.body.classList.add("ltr");
        document.body.classList.remove("rtl");
        } else {
        document.body.classList.add("rtl");
        document.body.classList.remove("ltr");
        }
        push(pathname, asPath, { locale: lng });
    };
    return (
        <div className="language">
            <div className="lan__country active us flex items-center cursor-pointer" onClick={toggleLanguage} >
                <div className="flag flag1">
                    <div className="dark-none">
                        <Image src="/en.svg" width="20" height="20"alt="us flag" className='dark-none' />
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-none dark-show">
                        <Image src="/lang_white.svg" width="20" height="20"alt="us flag" className='d-none dark-show' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="flag flag2">
                    <div className="dark-none">
                        <Image src="/en.svg" width="20" height="20"alt="us flag" className='dark-none' />
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-none dark-show">
                        <Image src="/lang_white.svg" width="20" height="20"alt="us flag" className='d-none dark-show' />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Language
```

How can I use the next.js library to translate Arabic text to English? I was able to change the direction by clicking on the button, but I also want to change the wording. I am solely responsible for the front end. this question is completed however you can post your answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that.
if you have dynamic text that coming from database, you can use i18 (https://www.i18next.com/) for translation.

if you just want change your hard code data to another language, you should write all your static data in an object in json file and seprate them by key(en:... , ar: ...)

example:

-> data.json

```js
{
  en:{
    "title":"This is En Language",
    "name":"My Name Is F"
  },
  ar:{
    "title":"سلام علیکم",
    "name":"تعلم"
  }
}
```

-> index.js

```js
import {data} from "./folder/data.json;
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Home=()=>{
  const {locale}=useRouter()
  const myData=data[locale]

  return (
    <div>
       <h1>title = {myData.title}</h1> 
       <p>Name = {myData.name} </p>
    </div>)
}
```

Comment: where i can found data.json file in my code there is no data.json file

Comment: You should create a json file out of pages directory and just import it.(of couse you can write your multi language file everywhere you want but its better to write them all in different folder like folder/data.json.

Answer (score 1):

get help from this official example
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-i18n-next-intl